# Quirk with objdump on binary files compiled on a different operating system

Tags: c, arm, objdump, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I have found some odd behavior when using objdump. For an example to describe this issue, consider the simple c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If I then compile using the command line:

arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -g --specs=nosys.specs -o foo.o foo.c

and run the command:

arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe -S foo.o

I can see the source code in the output

```
0000821c <main>:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    821c:       e52db004        push    {fp}            ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
    8220:       e28db000        add     fp, sp, #0
        return 0;
    8224:       e3a03000        mov     r3, #0
    8228:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
    822c:       e24bd000        sub     sp, fp, #0
    8230:       e49db004        pop     {fp}            ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
    8234:       e12fff1e        bx      lr
```

All well so far.

But if I copy the foo.o to a linux machine with the same toolchain and run the objdump command

```
0000821c <main>:
    821c:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
    8220:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
    8224:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
    8228:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
    822c:   e24bd000    sub sp, fp, #0
    8230:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
    8234:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

No Source code. It happens in the opposite direction, i.e compile in Linux and dump in Windows.

Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Did you also copy the source file?

Comment: @AndrewHenle no i didn't, as I had assumed the source code is embedded in the .o file. After your suggestion i did and it made no difference. Also on Windows (where compilation occoured) I have moved the foo.o to a sub folder (only file in the folder) and run the objdump and the source code is there. So this indicates my assumption is valid.

Comment: My first guess would be that the toolchain in use produces debug information in different formats on the different build architectures.

Comment: Make a new directory. Copy the source code into it. Perform the compilation. Execute `arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe -S foo.o` and check the output is as expected. Copy the entire directory to the Linux system. Check for hidden files in the original directory and ensure they are copied. Execute `arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe -S foo.o` on the Linux system. Does it show the source code? If not, repeat using a directory in the same path relative to your home directory on the origin system and the Linux system and repeat using a directory in the same absolute path…

Comment: … (Rationales: Copy the entire directory because some tools use auxiliary files to hold debug information. Use the same paths because the debug information in the object file might point to the source using an absolute path, or possibly a path relative to the home directory.) Also ensure `arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe` is the same version on both systems.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I had already done the first part of your suggestion before raising the question. On Windows Create empty directory, new C file, compile, dump. Copy obj file to Linux and then dump again. After Andrews suggestion I copied the source code and the still no source.

Comment: A linux aarch64 encodes full file paths.  You need to have the same path to find the source file.  They are not relative, but absolute.  It covers the use case where the build location is moved to an executable location, such as '/sbin', '/usr/bin', etc.  You can see the path with `strace -e trace=file objdump...` on Linux.  Also cross tool chains are **NOT** a normal use case.  `gdb` probably has more options.  If you use the '-l -d' options, you will see the full file name and line number.  You can script it to insert the text on Linux.

Comment: Re “Copy obj file to Linux”: No, that is not what I wrote. I wrote to copy **the entire directory**, not just the object file, nor just the object file and the source file.

Comment: @artlessnoise that makes all the sense, ran the strace on Linux with the .o file an the output shows that it could not find foo.c in the windows path. Conformation bias on my part. As a solution, I will run the objdump on the compiling architecture and take the list file to the other. BTW I wish you had put this up as a post as then I could mark it as an answer.

Comment: As source files are not limited to be only in one directory, I would expect that the debug information would includie full path to the source files that were used. This will not work if you have very different path names on Windows and Linux.